# .htacess mobile redirect stopped working

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mobile

My .htaccess mobile redirect code used to work. Now it stopped working. Does anyone know why?
Here's the code:

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.anumberoneanimalandpestcontrol.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^anumberoneanimalandpestcontrol.com$
rewritecond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTPS:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
# if the browser accepts these mime-types, it's definitely mobile, or pretending to be
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]

# a bunch of user agent tests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]

rewriterule ^$ http\:\/\/anumberoneanimalandpestcontrol\.com\/pest-control-baltimore-mobile\.html[R=301,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working" exactly? Do you get an error? Or literally, it's just "stopped working"?! There are some obvious errors (missing spaces before the _flags_) that will break the redirect - but that will have always broken the redirect? Also, what URLs are you requesting? Your `RewriteRule` only redirects requests for the document root.

Comment: It stopped redirecting. However, I have a sub-problem. When I test the site on Mobile Friendly Test, I get a response "failed to fetch the requested URL. I had a malware problem on the site, which I have cleared up, but that's not helping. As soon as I solve this problem I can try the various suggestions that people have made about altering the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove at least lines 3 through 7 because you're trying to detect very old phones with very small screens, and most mobile phones support standard HTML.

As for your rewrite rule, change:

```
rewriterule ^$ http\:\/\/anumberoneanimalandpestcontrol\.com\/pest-control-baltimore-mobile\.html[R=301,L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://anumberoneanimalandpestcontrol.com/pest-control-baltimore-mobile.html [R=301,L]
```

There always needs to be one space before the first square bracket when it starts a set of RewriteRule/RewriteCond parameters such as `[R=301,L]`.

I would suggest ditching most of your code except for lines 1, 2, and the last line and in between line 2 and the last line, add all the RewriteCond's in the apache code that you download from following this URL:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/